# What's the best way to map internal rails models to an external API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Whats the best way, to map your internal Rails models to external APIs?

#### Example

For e.g. if I have a model called `Car` with an attribute called `color` which in my case holds a bunch of different possible values like

```
- "red"
- "blue"
- "black"
- "green"
- ...
```

And now I might have to send an object of my class to another applications API which also knowns about cars but their colors are encoded in numbers or different codes like so:

```
- 0 == "black"       or       "Black paint" == "black"
- 1 == "white"       or       "White paint" == "white"
- 2 == "red"         or         "Red paint" == "red"
- ...
```

Is there some nifty way to map those values within Rails except with huge `switch: ... case: ...` assignments?

Comment: a `Hash` comes to mind

Answer (score 0):

You can make a hash... I'd be likely to put it in the `Car` model

```
API_COLORS = {'black' => 'inky', 'white' => 'snow'}
```

And you mioght want to use the hash only for colors encoded in the hash, in which cas you can then have an instance method in the `Car` moddel that returns the `API_COLORS` value if it exists, otherwise returns the normal color value.

```
def api_color
  API_COLORS[color] || color
end
```

And in your API you would send `my_car.api_color`